# How to extract values of dict with keys by map or lambda function

Tags: python, lambda

Now I got a dict:

```
d = {'key1':
        {'key11':1,
         'key12':2},
     'key2':
        {'key21':3,
         'key22':4}
    }
```

How to extract it to a list of tuple:

```
l = [('key1','key11',1),
     ('key1','key12',2),
     ('key2','key21',3),
     ('key2','key22',4)]
```

using map or lambda function
My Python version is Python2.7

Comment: _Why_ does it have to be `lambda` or `map`? They doesn't suit your needs.. an LC is fine here. That's like saying "Please build me a house, using a hammer". Just saying.

Comment: I see.. LC is OK too and I just got the answer below from @thefourtheye, I'll learn the detail including efficiency of LC later. Thank you all:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to get the output you wanted

```
print [(k, k1, d[k][k1]) for k in d for k1 in d[k]]
```

**Output**

```
[('key2', 'key22', 4),
 ('key2', 'key21', 3),
 ('key1', 'key12', 2),
 ('key1', 'key11', 1)]
```

If you want the output to be sorted, as in your question,

```
print sorted([(k, k1, d[k][k1]) for k in d for k1 in d[k]])
```

**Output**

```
[('key1', 'key11', 1),
 ('key1', 'key12', 2),
 ('key2', 'key21', 3),
 ('key2', 'key22', 4)]
```

Comment: Many thanks! How is the efficiency? Is it equals to: `for k,v in d.iteritems(): for k1,v1 in k: l.append((k, k1, d[k][k1]))` ?

Comment: @PeacefulBY [List comprehension will be faster than `l.append`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops).